# Как в помощью Asyncio создать функцию постоянно выполняющуюся на фоне

Tags: python, многопоточность, циклы, asyncio, асинхронность

Необходимо сделать цикл (как вариант библиотека Asyncio) который будет работать в фоне параллельно с работой основного кода. Этакая многопоточность.

Пример:

> пользователь вводит цифры в программу, а та выдает их в квадрате и каждые 10 минут выводит еще и время. Вывод каждые 10 минут не зависит от пользователя и происходит автоматически и параллельно с работой основного кода.

Нужен именно компактный блок кода, который будет работать по такой логике:

```
Выполняется код в основной функции (скажем итерация "1" в цикле)
Выполняется код в основной функции (итерация "2" в цикле)
...
Выполняется код в основной функции (итерация "Х" в цикле)

Когда прошло 10 минут код в фоновой функции выводит текущее время (основная функция при этом не останавливается)

Выполняется код в основной функции (итерация "Х+1" в цикле)
Выполняется код в основной функции (итерация "Х+2" в цикле)

Что-то далее...
```

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно реализовать? Буду благодарен за кусочек кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с asyncio:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress

async def echo_forever():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print("3 seconds passed")

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(echo_forever())

    for i in range(10):
        print(f'{i}^2 == {i^2}')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

def stop_all_tasks(loop):
    for task in asyncio.all_tasks(loop):
        task.cancel()
        with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
            loop.run_until_complete(task)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    stop_all_tasks(loop)
```

Comment: Какова может быть причина ошибки ```DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()```?

Comment: Вероятно вы запускаете этот код на питоне 3.10. Я пробовал на 3.9. В asyncio были изменения и нужна адаптация кода под 3.10. По идее достаточно заменить вызов `asyncio.get_event_loop()` на `asyncio.new_event_loop()`. Проверю, как установлю 3.10, и изменю ответ.

Comment: Так и есть. Подправил ответ - работает и в 3.9 и в 3.10.

Comment: Благодарю, информативно.